# How do i make the buttons reacts to the mouse click

Tags: java, swing, awt

Can someone help me making this question in my assignment " Make a program that will responds to a mouseclick by showing a message that indicates where the user clicked."

Here is my code

```
package testprogh;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;


public class Testprogh extends MouseInputAdapter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        JButton btn=new JButton("RIGHT");
        JButton btn2=new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton btn3=new JButton("CENTER");
        JButton btn4=new JButton("DOWN");
        JButton btn5=new JButton("UP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(btn2, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(btn3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btn4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(btn5, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Testprogh ha =new Testprogh();
        frame.addMouseListener(ha);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(ha);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
    }
}
```

But the problem here its not showing the message dialog

Comment: You should be adding an `ActionListener` to each button. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for examples. You should NOT be using a MouseListener for something like this. However, for future reference, the tutorial also has a section on `How to Write a MouseListener. You need to add the MouseListener to ALL the components, not the frame because you click on the button, not the frame.

Answer (score 0):

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;


public class TestProgh extends MouseInputAdapter {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton btn = new JButton("RIGHT");
        JButton btn2 = new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton btn3 = new JButton("CENTER");
        JButton btn4 = new JButton("DOWN");
        JButton btn5 = new JButton("UP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(btn, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(btn2, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(btn3, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(btn4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(btn5, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        TestProgh ha = new TestProgh();
        frame.addMouseListener(ha);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(ha);


        btn.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println("Mouse clicked on coordinates x : " + mouseEvent.getX() + " y : " + mouseEvent.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println("Mouse button pressed " + mouseEvent.getButton() + "on coordinates x : " + mouseEvent.getX() + " y : " + mouseEvent.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println("Mouse button released" + mouseEvent.getButton() + "on coordinates x : " + mouseEvent.getX() + " y : " + mouseEvent.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                // I don't know those
                System.out.println("Mouse entered in button area " + mouseEvent.getButton() + "on coordinates x : " + mouseEvent.getX() + " y : " + mouseEvent.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                System.out.println("Mouse exited button area" + mouseEvent.getButton() + "on coordinates x : " + mouseEvent.getX() + " y : " + mouseEvent.getY());
            }
        });
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have posted will not show the JOptionPane message dialog because your frame is full of button so when you click on any button mouseClicked event will not be triggered as it is added to JFrame. So you need to add MouseAdapter to a Button like the below.

```
btn.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          super.mouseClicked(e);
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "test");
      }
});
```

or

```
Testprogh ha =new Testprogh();
btn.addMouseListener(ha);
```